# How to set the CTRL + R in Windows button

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have the below code where I am expecting that when the user will press the CTRL +R , the program will be trigger

```
public Form1()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   button1.KeyPress +=new KeyPressEventHandler(button1_KeyPress);

 }

private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

   if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.ControlKey) && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```

But it is not working. Also the code is expected to run invariable of 'r' or 'R' is pressed.

Please help where I am making mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldnt understand what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to capture keypress events for example Ctrl+C for copy ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
            {
            }

        }
```

Comment: But I am encountring as for e.KeyCode == Keys.R part, e.KeyCode  value is coming as "LButton | ShiftKey" while for Keys.R  it is as Keys.R. And hence the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to be notified when certain combination of keys are pressed by user like Ctrl+C or Ctrl+f then you need to override ProcessCmdKey() method. You can find more information about this method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)